# Docusign programatically adding recipients

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm working on a system where I need to add envelope recipients programmatically.

I created a template on Docusign' side and then I'm using that template's Id to send out the envelopes to each recipient like so

```
    $planeType = $flight->planeType;
    $passengers = $flight->passengers;

    $TemplatesApi = new TemplatesApi();
    $TemplatesApi->setApiClient($apiClient);

    $templateId = $planeType->docusign_template_id;

    $recipientRoles = [];
    foreach ($passengers as $passenger) {
        $recipientRoles[] = new TemplateRole([
            'email' => $passenger->email,
            'name' => $passenger->name,
            'role_name' => 'passenger',
        ]);
    }

    $envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
        'email_subject' => 'Please sign this waiver.',
        'template_id' => $templateId,
        'template_roles' => $recipientRoles,
        'status' => 'sent',
    ]);

    try {
        $envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $envelopResults = $envelopesApi->createEnvelope($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelopeDefinition);

        if ($envelopResults) {
            $envelopeStatus = $envelopesApi->getEnvelope($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelopResults->getEnvelopeId());

            if ($envelopeStatus->getStatus() === 'sent') {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Waivers sent successfully', 'envelopeId' => $envelopResults->getEnvelopeId()]);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed to send waivers', 'envelopeStatus' => $envelopeStatus->getStatus()], 500);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed to update envelope status', 'error' => 'Unknown error'], 500);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Error sending waivers', 'error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
```

I can see the list of recipients in the Docusign template view get updated correctly, but the emails do not get sent out. Its only after i issue another request to send do the envelopes get sent.

Is that intended behavior? Does the template need to have a list of prefilled recipients before i can send envelopes to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is intended behavior.

You cannot "send" a template, you cannot request signatures on a templates, no one can sign or act on a template.

[A template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/) is just a way to create [envelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/envelopes/). It helps you because you can create similar type of envelopes again and again without having to specify the [documents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/) or [tabs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/) every time. The recipients can also be modified from the template if you need to.

An envelope that was already sent and awaiting signature cannot be modified directly by APIs, you need to first put it in "correct" mode to start a correction process. If the envelope is still in "draft" mode - you can still modify it.

I recommend (but it's not required) that you use the [composite template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/) method (instead of the code you share) which affords a lot more flexibility if your needs change later.

Here is some PHP code showing composite templates - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/AddDocToTemplateService.php

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. However i dont really need to edit the envelope itself just the recipient list. So if i understand you correctly, everytime i need to send envelopes(with reference to a template id), i'll need to clear out the list of recipients in the template and refill it with the target recipients that i want?

Comment: You could do it like that, yes, but remember to not change the envelope status to (send it) BEFORE you first update the recipients to what you want them to be...

Comment: One thing you may be confused about - you can have "placeholder" recipients, so you update their values, but not the name of the "role". with RecipientRoles, you can change the emails and names but still have the "same" recipients.

Comment: Thank you again brother! I ended up setting it to `sent` from the start.That was my initial implementation but i got confused when i saw the list of recipients not updating in the template after doing so.This led to setting it as draft and changing the recipients on the template itself.Im now adding the templateRoles to the envelope definition and then creating the envelope.One last question though please: i noticed that if i have more than 1 recipient and they all sign,the completed envelope will have all their signatures.Does that mean that i have to create an envelope for each recipient?

Comment: I edited the question with my current implementation.

Comment: no, you can have as many recipients as you want with as many tabs (signing elements) as you want in a single envelope

Comment: Gotcha. When i created the template, I set a recipient to receive copies of the signed envelopes. When i receive the signed copy though, it contains the signatures of all the recipients in a single document. Example: i had two recipients, each signed at the same location in the document, when i received a signed copy their signatures sat on top of the other.

Comment: should i not receive a signed document for each recipient? If yes, It does not seem to be functioning that way.

Comment: yes, you should, that's how it works. If you don't want that -  there's a way to do that